# Zeppelin Dynamic Forms: How to pass a variable into a dynamic form --OR-- reuse a dynamic form

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

Within Zeppelin, a jdbc paragraph can be parameterized to query according to input from a select form (dropdown) e.g.

```
%jdbc

SELECT *
FROM db.table
WHERE colA='${Value=0,0(a)|1(b)|2(c)}'
LIMIT 1
```

creates an output field with a dropdown menu Value (initialized to "a" corresponding to value 0 and having options "a", "b", "c"). Whenever a new Value is selected, the query runs. In this case returning one row of `table` for which `colA` has the value corresponding to the Value.

If a user selects "c" from the form, the query returns a row where `colA=2`.
See: [Zeppelin Dynamic Forms](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/dynamic_form/intro.html)

In a python paragraph, we could similarly create a using the [zeppelin context](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/usage/other_features/zeppelin_context.html) object z. Simply,

```
%python

value_list = [(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]
value_default = value_list[0]

z.select('Value',value_list,value_default)
```

Additionally, zeppelin contexts are able to share variables. In the python example above, I could add the line `z.put('valueDefault',value_default)` and use it in, say scala (`val valueDefault = z.get('valueDefault')`) or in a jdbc paragraph, I can refer to valueDefault as, `${valueDefault}` e.g.

```
%jdbc

SELECT *
FROM db.table
WHERE colA='${valueDefault}'
LIMIT 1
```

returns one row of `table` with `colA=0`.

My question is this: How can I either
(i) use---the equivalent of---a z.select inside a dynamic list specification

```
%jdbc

SELECT *
FROM db.table
WHERE colA='${Value=0,z.select(<variable_containing_list of tuples>)}'
LIMIT 1
```

desired outcome: a dynamic form (default value 0, list of options from a variable)

OR
(ii) define and reuse a dynamic list whose scope is the whole notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! The value of a dynamic form is output by the zeppelin context.

Step 1: create dynamic form using e.g. `%python` interpreter and `put` it's output in a variable, say `value_choice`:

```
%python

value_list = [(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]
value_default = value_list[0]

z.put('value_choice', z.select('Value', value_list, value_default));
```

Step 2: in some `%jdbc` paragraph, say "paragraph_1_1", use the variable:

```
%jdbc

SELECT *
FROM db.table
WHERE colA={value_choice}
LIMIT 1
```

BEWARE type mismatches. You may have to cast value_choice or colA.

Step 3 (Optional): Add a run dependency. In the `%python` paragraph, adding the line, `z.z.run("paragraph_1_1")` will rerun that paragraph each time the dynamic form's value is updated.